# Describe what is an algebra?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming

In the functional programming world, when I want to design an API, i will encounter the word algebra api. 
Could someone please describe, what an algebra is in FP in context of designing API.

Which components build an algebra api? Laws, operations, etc..?

There is a word primitive, what is a primitive exactly? Please with show me an example.

Comment: There's no such thing as "an algebra". `Algebra` is an area of mathematics. An `API` is something programmers can use. An `algebra API` is some code that programmers can use to do mathematical things.

Comment: No, has nothing to do with math algebra, but it calls as algebra.

Comment: Yes, there is such a thing as an algebra. [Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra) is an example. I don't think it's relevant to the question, but then I don't understand the question.

Comment: How *exactly* do you encounter this concept? Be more specific.

Comment: @zero_coding it actually does have quite a bit to do with math algebra, that's why it's called an algebra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are referring to is [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

**Product Type**

A common class of ADT is the product type.  As an example, a "user" can be described as a combination of "name", "email address", and "age":

```
case class User(name : String, email : String, age : Int)
```

This is called a "product" type because we can count the number of possible distinct Users using multiplication:

> distinct user count = (distinct name count) x (distinct email count) x (distinct age count)

**Sum Type**

The other common ADT class is the sum type.  As an example, a user can either be a common user or an adminstrator:

```
sealed trait User

case class CommonUser(name : String) extends User

case class AdminUser(name : String, powers : Set[AdminPowers]) extends User
```

This is called a "sum" type because we can count the number of possible distinct Users using addition:

> distinct user count = (distinct common user count) + (distinct admin user count)

Comment: Not at all. The approach of design an api and following law, etc?